# SoapHandler triggered prematurely

Tags: java, soap

I intercept the incoming and outgoing soap messages using a SoapHandler like this:

```
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
        boolean isResponse = (Boolean)context.get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

    if(!isResponse){
            logger.debug("MySoapHandler.handleMessage(): this is a soap request");
            SOAPMessage soapMsg = context.getMessage();
            SOAPMessage = createNewSoapRequest(soapMsg);
            context.setMessage(newSoapMsg);
    }
    else {
            logger.debug("MySoapHandler.handleMessage(): this is a soap response");            
            SOAPMessage soapMsg = context.getMessage();
            SOAPMessage newSoapMsg = createNewSoapResponse(soapMsg);
            context.setMessage(newSoapMsg);
    }
    return true;        
}
```

I receive the incoming soap message and replace it with a new one and send it on its way.  I can monitor the incoming message and its replacement and everything looks right.  If I comment out the incoming part and test the outgoing part by sending the correct request using SoapUI, the outgoing soap response is intercepted and replaced with a new message.  That too seems to work ok.

When I un-comment the incoming portion and let er' rip, the incoming one is triggered correctly, but the outgoing response seems to get triggered prematurely, before the main code for generating it has completed.  Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: What's the content of the response message? Any kind of fault that could be generated before the main code is even invoked?

Comment: Actually, I should have said "before the main code has completed".  It does start to run but I don't see any faults logged when suddenly the outgoing soap handler kicks in.  Wondering what can trigger it?

Comment: after more debugging, I found that 3 of 5 parameters in the soap message are null, causing the main code to return early.  now to figure out why they are null.  I can see the message being sent and they are not null